# what's the meaning of "the leadership is turning on itself"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Impatience is rising and **the leadership is turning on itself**. One camp wants Mrs May to sack Mr Johnson, who has been writing articles clearly dissenting from the government line; another camp wants to see the back of Philip Hammond, the chancellor, who is taking a cautious view of post-Brexit economic prospects.

Answer (score 1):

"Turning on" is being used to mean "blame/betray" in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

To turn on each other or to turn on oneself or itself=

The dog turned on his master. [bit him]

It means to fight with in your context, but can mean things like a dog biting a person too. They are fighting with each other.